# sysstat not updating configuration?

Tags: logging, services, redhat-enterprise-linux, centos-6, sysstat

This is my first question on SuperUser so go easy!

I have attempted to prune my servers' /var/log/sa/* logs by updating the /etc/sysconfig/sysstat file to the following:

```
# sysstat-10.1.5 configuration file.

# How long to keep log files (in days).
# If value is greater than 28, then log files are kept in
# multiple directories, one for each month.
HISTORY=7

# Compress (using gzip or bzip2) sa and sar files older than (in days):
COMPRESSAFTER=1

# Parameters for the system activity data collector (see sadc manual page)
# which are used for the generation of log files.
SADC_OPTIONS="-S DISK"

# Compression program to use.
ZIP="gzip"
```

Previously my config file would keep 28 days worth of files and compress every 31 days (never). After making the above update I ran:

```
service sysstat restart
```

To no avail - I have also noticed that there is the default cron job located in:

```
/etc/cron.d/sysstat
```

Which reads the following:

```
# Run system activity accounting tool every 10 minutes
*/10 * * * * root /usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1
# 0 * * * * root /usr/lib64/sa/sa1 600 6 &
# Generate a daily summary of process accounting at 23:53
53 23 * * * root /usr/lib64/sa/sa2 -A
```

Do I need to manually run the above or wait til' tomorrow? OR, does it have nothing to do with my restart and the cron jobs, meaning I'll just have to manually delete the unwanted saDD/sarDD logs?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Literally answered my own question within 5 minutes by simply manually running:
    /usr/lib64/sa/sa2 -A

From the above cron job as root.

I'll leave my question/answer as it may help somebody out in future.